# Laravel sanctum to give access to api for not logged in user if coming through application

Tags: api, token, laravel-8, laravel-sanctum

I am building an app in react native and using laravel 8 application and sanctum to expose the APIs.

I want to expose API to non logged in user who are trying to access through phone (they can browse through app without login). Since sanctum issues token to logged-in user, is it possible to restrict the APIs based on one universal token?